# Concatenating string passed into a control sequence

Tags: bash, colors, string, echo

I have this `echo` invocation that prints a blue bar in a Bash terminal:

```
echo $'\e[48;2;0;0;255m                \e[0m'
```

I would like to pass some variables to it, something like (this doesn't work):

```
rgb_blue=42
echo $'\e[48;2;0;0;"$rgb_blue"m                \e[0m
```

Is there any way to do that? I tried the usual ways of concatenating strings in Bash but none of them worked.

Comment: With current `bash`: `echo -e '\e[48;2;0;0;'"${rgb_blue}"'m                \e[0m'`

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. But you need the `$' '` for the colors. So you need to combine the two. Something like this should work:

```
echo $'\e[48;2;0;0;'"${rgb_blue}"$'m                \e[0m'
```

Or, probably simpler:

```
printf '\e[48;2;0;0;%dm                \e[0m\n' "$rgb_blue"
```